# UIButton.setTitleColor(_, for: ) not working on an outlet, only on sender in action

Tags: ios, swift

`newGameButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)` does not work on an outlet. It only works for me on an action where the button is the sender of the action.

Every answer I have found addresses just using `setTitleColor` as the solution to setting a UIButton's text color, but not the actual problem of it not working.

```
@IBOutlet var newGameButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() 
        super.viewDidLoad()
        newGameButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
}

@IBAction func touchCard(_ sender: UIButton) {
        newGameButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
}
```

It seems like when I set the color to black in `viewDidLoad()`,
it actually changes the color of the button for state selected 
but does nothing else.

The desired changed does happen when you do `setTitleColor` on
the `sender` in the `touchCard` method.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, because if you have already set the title color to black in `viewDidLoad` there is no change to make if you set the title color to black in `touchCard` — the button's title color is black already.

Comment: Also, at the risk of sounding repetitive, I'm going to suggest what I've suggested on other answers, namely that the simulator is buggy on your machine. I often find that on older machines the simulator does not update its appearance the way you expect.

Comment: I am showing two separate examples. I set the color in viewDidLoad and the text color does not change I do not set the color in the touchCard method. If I remove the line of code that is supposed to change the text from viewDidLoad and put it in the touchCard method and call it on sender, it DOES change the text color properly.

What I am trying to convey is that setTitleColor() is only working on the 'sender' (button being pressed) of an action and not working on an outlet that is a button.

Comment: Can you double check to what UI element to your outlet is connected? Perhaps your outlet is connected to other element.

Comment: My second comment applies. It should work so maybe the failure is just an illusion caused by Simulator issues on your machine.

Comment: It is most definitely connected to the correct button. And if it was a simulation error, then why would it work on sender in touchCard?

Comment: Who knows? The simulator can be very buggy, failing to update the interface correctly in an unreliable way. It's not my job to describe or justify its bugginess. Try running your app on a device if you want to eliminate the possibility that this is just the simulator misleading you.

Comment: Ok Ill give that a shot. Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Excellent, let me know what you find out. If that doesn't fix it, upload a demo project to github or similar so we can try running it for ourselves.

Comment: I found the issue. I hovered over the @IBOutlet and saw that the button was looking like it was connected, but when I actually inspected the button's connections by right clicking it, it was indeed not connected. Sorry for the wild goose chase guys. I appreciate your help.